# Сохранение размеров изображений в контейнере flex

Tags: html, css, css3

Как запретить контейнеру `flex` масштабировать изображения внутри него? Размер изображений не фиксированный, может быть разный, и они должны отображаться в полном размере.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}
.img1 {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.img2 {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "flexbox">
  <img src = "http://file.mobilmusic.ru/9f/a9/d6/1000877-128.jpg" class = "img1">
  <div>
  <p>Каждый веб-разработчик знает, что такое текст-«рыба». Текст этот, несмотря на название, не имеет никакого отношения к обитателям водоемов.</p>
  <p>Используется он веб-дизайнерами для вставки на интернет-страницы и демонстрации внешнего вида контента, просмотра шрифтов, абзацев, отступов и т.д.</p>
  </div>
  <img src = "http://s020.radikal.ru/i713/1304/42/b4d938de22e4.jpg" class = "img2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может потребоваться автопрефиксер.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.flexbox div {
  flex: 1 1;
}

.img1 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  object-fit: none;
}

.img2 {
  margin-right: 50px;
  object-fit: none;
}
```

```html
<div class = "flexbox">
  <img src = "http://file.mobilmusic.ru/9f/a9/d6/1000877-128.jpg" class = "img1">
  <div>
  <p>Каждый веб-разработчик знает, что такое текст-«рыба». Текст этот, несмотря на название, не имеет никакого отношения к обитателям водоемов.</p>
  <p>Используется он веб-дизайнерами для вставки на интернет-страницы и демонстрации внешнего вида контента, просмотра шрифтов, абзацев, отступов и т.д.</p>
  </div>
  <img src = "http://s020.radikal.ru/i713/1304/42/b4d938de22e4.jpg" class = "img2">
</div>
```

Comment: По-моему, в данном примере вообще достаточно обернуть img в div'ы, по аналогии с текстом

Comment: Согласен. Но css я люблю больше. )

Comment: object-fit - не поддерживается ни где кроме оперы , для чего это писать ?

Comment: @Geyan правда? http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: пардон Сэр , обознался - с htmlbook.ru инфа была

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit  хотя тут  написано что в IE  не работает

Comment: @Geyan ваша табличка от свойства с браузерным префиксом -o-object-fit, потому и указана поддержка только оперой. в IE да, не работает. Но у flex в ie тоже ограниченная поддержка.

Comment: какая табличка ? я ж с MDN ссылку дал

Comment: @Geyan у вас была ссылка на скриншот была сохранненый в облако мэйл.ру. на скриншоте табличка c htmlbook.ru. Не надо подчищать коменты. про информацию с MDN я вам ответил.

Comment: вы ответили ссылкой с canuise а я как раз с mdn

Comment: т.е. мне вот эта ссылка https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9XK9/VxkGkQCzw привиделась? слава богу в браузерах есть журнал и я даже скриншот снял... не надо так делать. в конце концов вас тут не съедят за то что вы были не внимательны. всем пофигу.

Comment: я же написал что я давал ссылку с htmlbook - я думал не успел заметь